# xaxis label positioning (2D)

Tags: python, matplotlib, position

```
headings=[['Jan to Feb'], ['Feb to Mar'], ['Mar to Apr'], ['Apr to May'], ['May to June'], ['Jun to July'], ['July to Aug'], ['Aug to Sep'], ['Sep to Oct'], ['Oct to Nov']]
incoming=[[27, 42, 66, 85, 65, 64, 68, 68, 77, 58],
        [24, 39, 58, 79, 60, 62, 67, 62, 55, 35],
        [3, 3, 8, 6, 5, 2, 1, 6, 22, 23],
        [3, 3, 8, 6, 5, 2, 1, 6, 22, 23],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       ]
joint=[[486, 511, 615, 825, 760, 693, 848, 639, 651, 657]
     [444, 482, 562, 793, 729, 666, 812, 599, 592, 597]
     [42, 29, 53, 32, 31, 27, 36, 40, 59, 60]
     [29, 28, 35, 32, 31, 27, 36, 40, 59, 60]
     [13, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
```

See Photo:
http://s1362.photobucket.com/user/superempl/media/figure_1_zps782354d7.png.html

I need to shift the x-axis labels to the right.  I've tried:

```
plot.set_xticklabels(headings,multialignment='right')
```

but this had no effect.

Could someone explain what must be done to alter the position of these labels to the centre of each bar.

My code is as follows:

```
import pylab as p
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

fig = p.figure(figsize=(20,8))
plot = fig.add_subplot(111)            

ind = range(len(headings))          

bar1 = plot.bar(ind,joint[0],facecolor='#777777')
bar2 = plot.bar(ind,outgoing[0],facecolor='#B0E0E6')

# x-axis
plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(10))
plot.set_xticklabels(headings)

p.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, try the following:

```
# headings should be simple list
headings=['Jan to Feb', 'Feb to Mar', 'Mar to Apr', 'Apr to May', 'May to June',
          'Jun to July', 'July to Aug', 'Aug to Sep', 'Sep to Oct', 'Oct to Nov']
```

Center bars on the ticks with `align='center'`:

```
bar1 = plot.bar(ind,joint[0],facecolor='#777777', align='center')
```

Then set tick position and tick labels:

```
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(ind)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(h)

ax.set_xlim(ind[0]-.5,ind[-1]+.5)  # set width of axis
fig.canvas.draw()  # don't forget to draw changes
```

That way the labels will be centered below the bars:
  [image: Example Bars]

See the matplotlib gallery (e.g., [2](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo2.html), [3](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html)) for further usage examples.